# Powershell Hotkey to Erase Current Line?

Tags: powershell, console, inline-editing

I would like to execute a hotkey that would erase the current line in the powershell session. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> works for me

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work.  Ctrl-C also effectively does the same thing.

Answer (score 13):

Besides using <kbd>Esc</kbd> to clear the whole line, you can also use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to erase from the current position back to the beginning, or
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to erase from the current position to the end.